# Dataloader Condition: Accounts with Contacts, Opportunities, etc.?

Tags: data-loader, conditional

Is there a way in Dataload to add the condition when exporting Accounts so that it only pulls Accounts with Contacts, Opportunities, etc.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This pattern generally takes the form of a [semi-join](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm):

```
SELECT Id, ....
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT AccountId
    FROM SomeChildObject
)
```

Make sure to use the actual name of the relationship field in the sub-select.

Comment: So just paste this in the Query?

SELECT Id, ....
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT AccountId
    FROM Contacts
)

Comment: @Steve You will need to modify this pattern to suite whatever else you're trying to accomplish, e.g., populating the SELECT clause, and you must use the action sObject name `Contact` in the sub-select.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I'm confused by what you are saying.

Comment: I just want to only export accounts that actually have contacts and opportunities.

Comment: @Steve Performing an extraction works by generating a query. To achieve what you wish to do in Data Load, you'll need to modify that query in the UI for doing an extract operation. You will need to take the existing query you're using (particularly its SELECT clause, which defines what data you want on each record), and add one or more semi-join clauses in the `WHERE` clause along the pattern above.

Comment: You could do `WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact) AND Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity)`. I believe the limit is two, though.